# Calling System.loadLibrary() via JNI does not load native methods

Tags: c++, java-native-interface

We have a native C++ application that creates an embedded JVM.  Classes in this JVM call back into C++ object methods using SWIG wrappers (although SWIG use is not important; it could just as easily have been native function stubs produced from javah).  For example, We have a Java class with a native method like:

```
package net.foo;
public class CppWrapJNI {
  public final static native long foo(
    long l, Stuff jarg1_, String s
  );
}
```

There is a corresponding implementation in a C++ DLL:

```
extern "C" {
  __declspec(dllexport) jlong JNICALL 
  Java_net_foo_CppWrapJNI_1foo(
    JNIEnv *jenv, jclass jcls, 
    jlong jarg1, jobject jarg1_, jstring jarg2
  ) {
    return 1;
  }
}
```

Let's say this DLL is named "foo.dll".

We then attempt to have the JVM load the DLL through JNI, using code like the following:

```
jclass cls = env->FindClass("java/lang/System");
jmethodID mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(
  cls, "loadLibrary", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V"
);
jstring jstr = env->NewStringUTF("foo.dll");
env->CallStaticVoidMethodV(cls, mid, jstr);
```

This all works, and the call to loadLibrary() reports no error (JNI exception processing not shown here, but we do it).  However, a later call to CppWrapJNI.foo() fails with an error like:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
net.foo.CppWrapJNI.foo(JLnet/foo/Stuff;Ljava/lang/String;)J
```

Oddly, if I write a test harness purely in Java, call loadLibrary the same way, everything works.  This was quite frustrating, since everything I could read online indicated that this should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I looked at the source for System.loadLibrary:

```
@CallerSensitive
public static void loadLibrary(String libname) {
    Runtime.getRuntime().loadLibrary0(Reflection.getCallerClass(), libname);
}
```

Aha!  The Reflection.getCallerClass() was the key.  There is no caller class!  It is coming from straight C++.  The solution was rather simple, to write a facade around System.load*() that we can call from C++ and which will turn around and call the System method:

```
public class SystemFacade {
    public static void load(String path) {
        java.lang.System.load(path);
    }
    public static void loadLibrary(String name) {
        java.lang.System.loadLibrary(name);
    }
}
```

And voila, it works.  Presumably, any variation in which java made the call instead of C++ via JNI would also avoid the problem.  The @CallerSensitive tag seems to be a clue; don't call these via JNI!  I hope this post saves someone else the frustration I went through.  I am still puzzled about why the load seemed to succeed but then no symbols were found.

Comment: Why are you going to such troubles just to call `dyload` or `LoadLibraryEx`?

Comment: Because LoadLibraryEx doesnt make C++ code callable by java.  Our app is a significant c++/java hybrid and both languages call each other.  I dont actually write that JNI code.  we have a sopisticated wrapper-generator that makes these calls one liners from c++.  Loading the native libs is just a tiny part of the integration effort.  it was easy to make the call from c++ as we spun up the embedded jvm.  Except that it did not work as expected, and a significant amount of effort was spent to find the cause.  i am going to write a blog about jni pitfalls.

Comment: Gotcha.  That makes sense.  Interested to see the blog post, I hope that you link it here.

Comment: I would also be interested in reading more about this integration effort! I'm sure I could learn much.

Comment: It is also worth noting, that you have to load the library in Java, even when the so/dll has already been loaded by the native code that makes the embedded JVM.